# Insert data into fusion chart using javascript and jsp

Tags: javascript, java, fusioncharts

I am using fusion charts in my jsp to present data. Here is the code I am using.

```
FusionCharts.ready(function(){
var summaryChart = new FusionCharts(  
{
    type: "line",
    renderAt: "chartContainer1",
    width: "500",
    height: "300",
    dataFormat: "json",
    "dataSource":  {
"chart": {
    "caption": "Total Revenues from 2008-2013",
    "numberprefix": "$",
    "bgcolor": "FFFFFF",
    "showalternatehgridcolor": "0",
    "plotbordercolor": "008ee4",
    "plotborderthickness": "3",
    "showvalues": "0",
    "divlinecolor": "CCCCCC",
    "showcanvasborder": "0",
    "tooltipbgcolor": "00396d",
    "tooltipcolor": "FFFFFF",
    "tooltipbordercolor": "00396d",
    "numdivlines": "2",
    "yaxisvaluespadding": "20",
    "anchorbgcolor": "008ee4",
    "anchorborderthickness": "0",
    "showshadow": "0",
    "anchorradius": "4",
    "chartrightmargin": "25",
    "canvasborderalpha": "0",
    "showborder": "0"
},

"data": [
    {
        "label": "2009",
        "value": "4400000",
        "color": "008ee4"
    },
    {
        "label": "2010",
        "value": "4800000",
        "color": "008ee4"
    },
    {
        "label": "2011",
        "value": "5500000",
        "color": "008ee4"
    },
    {
        "label": "2012",
        "value": "6700000",
        "color": "008ee4",
        "anchorradius": "7",
        "tooltext": "Historical high"
    },
    {
        "label": "2013",
        "value": "4200000",
        "color": "008ee4"
 }
 ]
 }
   });
 summaryChart.render();
 });
```

I want to add some data that has been read from the database as data to this chart. I tried using arrays inside javascipt and the stuff and still unable to do that.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can do it by using fusioncharts jsp wrapper

http://www.fusioncharts.com/jsp-charts/

More details about this wrapper

http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/using-with-server-side-languages/java/introduction.html